# Minimize Delphi Application with Live Popup Menu

Tags: delphi, minimize, popupmenu

I'm attempting to run this in a timer:

```
Application.Minimize;
ShowWindow( Application.handle, SW_HIDE );
```

It's been in the code forever and we just discovered that it doesn't work when you have a popupmenu active, it doesn't minimize the MDI parent window.

I figure if I can close the popup menu before running this code, then I'll be ok.  Problem is, this code is in an MDI Parent and I have no idea where the current popup menu is.  It doesn't matter if it's part of another form's tool bar, this forms tool bar, the product of a right click or that seemingly pointless key next to the space bar.

So, is there a way to hide the active popup menu in my entire program?

Also, if there's a better hunk of code than what I'm using to minimize that'll circumvent this issue, that'd be awesome info too.

Comment: I created a simple project with a popup menu and set the form's popup menu to point to this popup menu.  I run my application, right click on the form to activate the popup menu, but the application still minimizes when the timer fires your code.  Are you sure you don't have a "showModal" somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, I do have a show modal.  When the application minimizes, another form pops up, which is the logon form for the program.  And everything works perfectly unless there's a popup menu in the somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To close a popup menu you can use

```
  if GetCapture <> 0 then
    SendMessage(GetCapture, WM_CANCELMODE, 0, 0);
```

in your code before you try to minimize the form.

Comment: COOL! The GetCapture API is AWESOME!